# What does 'H' in BamHI stand for?

Tags: restriction-enzymes

It's not explained on the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BamHI) page. So if, apparently, 'H' is not relevant, why is it part of the name? And if it is relevant, why is it not explained?

Answer (score 7):

These enzymes are named by the bacteria and the strain from which they are isolated. For BamHI this is Bacillus amyloliquefaciens strain H. In the beginning the enzyme was named BamI, which was later changed to BamHI.

See these two references:

- [Isolation of a sequence-specific endonuclease (BamI) from Bacillus
  amyloliquefaciens H.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1177312)
- [Recognition sequence of specific endonuclease BamH.I from Bacillus
  amyloliquefaciens H.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/834250)

The same is true for all the other restriction enzymes, so is EcoRI the first restriction endonuclease isolated from Escherichia coli strain R.